# How can I make full height & dynamic width to paragrpah inside flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am studying flex box and here I created a flex box with 3 `p` items. The first one & last one is `content-fit` width. The middle one is variable width with `text-align:left`.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

li #title {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li p {
  padding: 0 14px;
}

li #title p:first-child {
  background-color: rgb(76, 0, 255);
}

li #title p:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff9100;
}

li #title p:last-child {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

li #description {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="title">
        <p>23 FEB 2020</p>
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
        <p>#12</p>
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        <p>Some text here.....</p>
        <p>Some text here.....</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

The very first problem is I can't make it full height for `p` inside flex box.

The second problem is the dynamic width for the middle `p` tag. I tried to set `100%` for `width` & `height` but It's not worked.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1 problem -> try to add margin:0 to your p. without it yur div takes the height of the p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin` and `flex` property. `margin` property is applied by user agent stylesheet.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

li #title {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li p {
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 0;
  /* add */
}

li #title p:first-child {
  background-color: rgb(76, 0, 255);
}

li #title p:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
  /* add */
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff9100;
}

li #title p:last-child {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

li #description {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="title">
        <p>23 FEB 2020</p>
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
        <p>#12</p>
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        <p>Some text here.....</p>
        <p>Some text here.....</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```